# Fetch more data on click in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

I have included more information to clarify the problem that I have.

My purpose is to create a load more button. On click, page number should dynamically increment. How can I put the result of the function `incrementPage()` in `api.pageNum` each time the button is clicked? `catchInput()` and `getResults()` I am also using to fetch data on input.

After clicking at the button the fetched data from the input is accompanied by the fetched data from button click.

```
import './styles.css';
import _ from 'lodash';
import template from './templates/template.hbs';

const api = {
  key: '###',
  querySearch: '',
  pageNum: 1,
};

const refs = {
  list: document.querySelector('.gallery'),
  form: document.querySelector('#search-form'),
  input: document.querySelector('input'),
  button: document.querySelector('button'),
};

refs.input.addEventListener('input', _.debounce(catchInput, 700));

function catchInput() {
  getResults(refs.input.value);
}

function incrementPage() {
  api.pageNum += 1;
}

function getResults(querySearch) {
  refs.list.innerHTML = '';
  if (querySearch.length > 0) {
    fetch(
      `https://pixabay.com/api/?image_type=photo&orientation=horizontal&q=${querySearch}&page=${api.pageNum}&per_page=12&key=${api.key}`,
    )
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) return response.json();
        throw new Error(
          `${response.status} error while your search has occured`,
        );
      })
      .then(pic => {
        const info = pic.hits.map(item => template(item)).join('');
        refs.list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', info);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
    incrementPage();
  }
}

refs.button.addEventListener('click', catchInput);
```

html

```
  <body>
    <form class="search-form" id="search-form">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="query"
        autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="Search images..."
      />
    </form>
    <ul class="gallery"></ul>
    <button class="btn-primary is-hidden" data-action="load-more">
      Load more
    </button>
```

Comment: It's not clear...is there a specific fault with this code currently? If you just want to refactor working code, that's not really what we do here. There is a Code Review StackExchange site. You could check their on-topic guidance and see if your question would fit better there.

Comment: can u include the code for refs.input

Comment: @ElMuchacho when you say "not working", you mean the catchInput function never runs, or you get a console error, or something else? Please be specific. If you can't answer that question, then it means you didn't do any basic debugging. Also we don't even know if `refs.button` is a valid reference. We need more info.

Comment: @ADyson sorry for being so misdetailed. I have included more information. If you can help, that'd be awesome.

Comment: @wowow yes! thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Are you absolutely sure the function isn't executing? If we reduce your code to the minimal, we can see that the function definitely would run, if no other error / problem is getting in the way. Watch the console in this demo, after you've pressed the button: https://jsfiddle.net/xLctb05s/ . Notice that the "here" log is shown, proving that the function would execute. I suggest you double-check your own version for errors.

Comment: Sir, about executing I can say that I'm not getting a fetched data on clicking, that's why I'm curious about finding what I can do with refactoring the function to make fetch on click happen. @ADyson

Comment: not getting a result is very different from saying the function is not executing. Different symptom, different cause. Please ensure you do enough logging and debugging of your code to be able to tell the difference.

Comment: So...if you think you're not getting the fetched data, now you need to debug what is actually happening instead. Have you watched your browser's Network tab to see what happens to your API request?

Comment: @ADyson, thank you so much sir! I'll do it right now. Sorry one more time for missunderstanding question

Comment: You don't need to apologise. Sometimes it's hard to know what information is relevant, especially if you are not experienced at debugging your code yet. That's what these comments are for, so we can help to clarify your question.

Comment: Alright now I get the problem: the debounce was working so slow, so I was just skipping the page and didn't waited for getting result, lol. But now I have another problem: after clicking at the button the fetched data from the input is accompanied by the fetched data from button click. @ADyson

Comment: Do you mean that the previous search results stay there, and the new results are added as well? If so, that's because you're only inserting results, and never removing the previous ones.

Comment: You should always `encodeURIComponent()` your query params, especially the `querySearch`

Comment: No, no, no - I mean the opposite: the data which is fetched by input is just refreshing by the data fetched by click. So, instead of enhancing it's changing. – @ADyson

Comment: Oh hang on I think it's because of `refs.list.innerHTML = '';`. This is clearing the list every time before you run the search. Sorry, my previous statement was incorrect.

Comment: yes! indeed! thank you!

Comment: Does that fix everything for you?

Comment: I think I have to change a getResults() function - I can't use it right now both for input and button @ADyson

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly if you want to get the current page number, You can use this method instead of yours:

```js
let url = window.location.href;
let pageNum = url[url.indexOf("&page=") + 6];
console.log(pageNum);
```